# Is keytar playable with both hands?

Tags: keyboard, midi-controller-keyboard, keytar

Most of the pictures showing keytar players show them playing with one hand only. Is it practically possible to use it to play pieces that require both hands while "wearing" the instrument with a strap the way it is designed to be played?

Obviously, it is possible to use both hands if you just place the keytar on the table in front of you.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. David Hirschfelder used to do that with LRB:

though he's miming, not playing live in that video.

The best way to play a Keytar is to drop it off the top of a tall building. It makes a pleasing sound when it shatters.

Comment: I don't know much about a Keytar but it does appear to be a workable solution to a keyboardist inability to move about the stage in a live performance.  So in the very limited application that it is designed for, it a solves a problem.  I know an accordion may also permit a "keyboardist" to move around, but may not provide the sound one requires.  In other words, Keytar has it's place.  Zendrum does the same for a drummer.